# Why is there a time gap bigger than a cycle when measuring a cycle with perf?

Tags: time, cpu, performancecounter, perf

I used the command `perf record -a` to measure the performance counters on my system and `perf script` to obtain the results, which look like this

`[000] 109528.087598:          1 cycles
[000] 109528.100038:       5072 cycles
[000] 109528.120034:       4878 cycles
[000] 109528.144032:       4514 cycles`

Let's say I am running this on a 3.3GHz CPU. From the formula `CPU freq = number of cycles / time` we get that in a microsecond we have 3.3 * 10^3 cycles.

My question is why does it take on average 3.95 microseconds to measure one cycle, when from the formula it should clearly take less?

Comment: My first intuitive thought was that this situation was caused by the CPU doing other operations before it starts executing another function (therefore using cycles), but I am not sure if this is the real reason.

Comment: `Perf record` does the sampling - which means that perf will generate around 1000 - 4000 interrupts per second, and to get them it will setup performance counter to some amount of cycles. Perf record (or perf report / perf script) may also hide samples hit idle processes. To get number of cpu clock cycles, use `perf stat` tool which will use counting mode of PMU.

Answer (score 1):

`perf record` does the sampling - which means that perf will generate around 1000 - 4000 interrupts per second, and to get them it will setup performance counter to some amount of cycles (probably different between interrupts). It only records to `perf.data` when the interrupt was received and what was instruction address at the moment. `perf report` will report in units of "sample", not in exact ticks.

Perf record (or perf report / perf script) may also hide samples hit idle processes.

To get number of cycles, use `perf stat` / `perf stat -a` tool which will use counting mode of PMU. This mode will also do frequency calculation for you and print average effective frequency of CPU.